# Array of pointers to array of struct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I'm a C beginners and I need help.
I've a struct like this the following one:

```
    struct {
        char*   name;
        int     level;
        int     spring_prob;
        int     population;
    } Organism;
```

Organism with the same level have to be grouped into the same array to create a situation like that:

```
    +++++         +++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    | 0 |  -->    | organism_0 | organism_1 |
    +++++         ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    | 1 |         | organism_2 | organism_3 | organism_4 |
    +++++         ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    | 2 |         | organism_5 |
    +++++         ++++++++++++++
     org
```

In *main* i created an array to pointer to array of struct:

```
    int main {
        ...
        Organism *org[];
        load_organism(org);
        show(org);
        return 0;
    }
    void load_organism (Organism *org[]){
        Organism o[3];
        o[0].name = "abc";
        o[0].level = 0;
        o[0].spring_prob = 25;
        o[0].population = 300;

        o[1].name = "def";
        o[1].level = 0;
        o[1].spring_prob = 25;
        o[1].population = 20;

        o[2].name = "ebs";
        o[2].level = 0;
        o[2].spring_prob = 25;
        o[2].population = 20;

        *org[0] = o;
    }
    void show (Organism* org[]) {
        print("%s", org[0][0].name);
    }
```

It crashes when i try to print the *name* of the first organism.
I hope you could help me finding the error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am surprised the compiler did not treat `Organism *org[];` as an error.

Comment: `int main {` ist not valid.

Comment: What compiler and toolchain are you using? The code you've posted is not valid C.

Comment: you have not allocated org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be seeing a number of compiler warnings with that code.

For example, when you assign `o` (which is an `Organism[]`) to `*org[0]`, which is an `Organism`. Heed those warnings.

In this case, you mean to say:

```
org[0] = o;
```

But that will fail eventually, since `o` is a local variable, and its memory will be discarded when the function returns.

Create it, instead, as:

```
Organism *o = malloc(3 * sizeof(Organism));
```

Once those are cleaned up, you'll need to actually allocate some memory to `org`, which is uninitialized. Bad news when you assign to its members.

Either give the array a specific size like so:

```
Organism *org[10];
```

or allocate it as above:

```
Organism **org = malloc(10 * sizeof(Organism *));
```

or

```
Organism **org = calloc(10, sizeof(Organism *));
```

When the program exits, be sure to `free()` any members of `org`, and `org` itself if you go the `malloc()` route.

Comment: `calloc` is specifically useful here to (1) provide a **sentinel null** following the last assigned organism to aid in iteration, and (2) to prevent the unintentional **attempted access of an uninitialized value**. In many situations `calloc` provides significant advantage over `malloc`, especially in saving a new C programmer from him or her selves.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you are defining an **empty** array of pointers to `Organism`. Then you access offset 0 of this array (which is already undefined behavior) and the garbage that is there used as a pointer to a memory which should now hold the copy of `o`. (Also I don't know how you managed to compile this line: `*org[0] = o;`)

Agree with me that even you would segfault at some moment :).

Either define a fixed size of this array:

```
#define NUM_OF_ORGANISMS 10

int main()
{
    Organism *org[NUM_OF_ORGANISMS];
    ....
}
```

and then in `load_organism` you need actually to allocate the memory for the new `Organism`:

```
org[0] = malloc(sizeof(Organism));
*org[0] = o[0];
```

Or define `org` as

```
Organism** org;
```

And then dynamically allocate the size of the array and each entry of it.

```
org = malloc(sizeof(Organism*)*NUM_OF_ORGANISMS);
....
org[i] = malloc(sizeof(Organism));
...
// now you can access it
*org[i] = ...
```

P.S.

And don't forget to `free` the memory after you finish using it :)

Comment: `Organism *org[];` is illegal code  , it is not an empty array or anything else. There are no empty arrays in C.

Answer (score 0):

The array `Organism o[3];` scope is limited to the function `void load_organism()`.

You are trying to access it after the function has exited. This invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

- You must mean that `org[0] = o;` instead of `*org[0] = o;`. So, it
  means `o` and `org[0]` are pointer to same address.
- However, you must mean `printf("%s", org[0]->name);` instead of
  `print("%s", org[0][0].name);`.
- Besides, If you want to use `Organism` like in `main()` and functions, you should
  add `typedef` to your struct.
- You need to initialize explicit size of the struct array or allocation
- Eventually, `o` is of course local variable for `load_organism` after function invoking it will be destroyed. You should use `malloc()`

Fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char*   name;
    int     level;
    int     spring_prob;
    int     population;
} Organism;

void load_organism (Organism *org[]){
    Organism *o = malloc(3 * sizeof(Organism));
    o[0].name = "abc";
    o[0].level = 0;
    o[0].spring_prob = 25;
    o[0].population = 300;

    o[1].name = "def";
    o[1].level = 0;
    o[1].spring_prob = 25;
    o[1].population = 20;

    o[2].name = "qwe";
    o[2].level = 0;
    o[2].spring_prob = 25;
    o[2].population = 20;

    org[0] = o;
}
void show (Organism* org[]) {
    printf("%s", org[0]->name);
}

int main()
{
    Organism *org[3];
    load_organism(org);
    show(org);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is UB - you're referencing memory from `o` after leaving the scope of `load_organism`.

Comment: Downvote removed; the original code had `o` as a local prior to editing, which must have been within the 5-minute grace period.